# Xamarin Forms Service checking incoming sms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I'd like to create a service to "start" an SMSReceived Broadcastreceiver?
How can I do this in Xamarin Forms (especially Android)?

I changed the following code to solve my question.
It's native Android code.
I call this class with DependendyServices in the "Main Activity" of the main project.

The Broadcastreceiver which created by the method "CheckForIncommingSMS" of "SMSHelper" works fine (it's also called when the app is running).

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using System;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(NAMESPACE.BackgroundServiceHelper))]
namespace NAMESPACE
{
    [Service(Name = "APPNAME.BackgroundService")]
    class BackgroundServiceHelper : Service, IBackgroundServiceHelper
    {

        static readonly string TAG = typeof(BackgroundServiceHelper).FullName;
        static readonly int DELAY_BETWEEN_LOG_MESSAGES = 5000; // milliseconds

        DateTime timestamper;
        bool isStarted;
        Handler handler;
        Action runnable;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            Log.Info(TAG, "OnCreate: the service is initializing.");

            timestamper = new DateTime();
            handler = new Handler();

            runnable = new Action(() =>
            {
                if (timestamper != null)
                {
                    Log.Debug(TAG, DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString());
                    
                    
                    SMSHelper smsh = new SMSHelper();
                    
                    // Method which registers the SMSReceived BrodcastReceiver
                    smsh.CheckForIncommingSMS();
                                
                    handler.PostDelayed(runnable, DELAY_BETWEEN_LOG_MESSAGES);
                }
            });
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if (isStarted)
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "OnStartCommand: This service has already been started.");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "OnStartCommand: The service is starting.");
                DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();
                handler.PostDelayed(runnable, DELAY_BETWEEN_LOG_MESSAGES);
                isStarted = true;
            }

            // This tells Android not to restart the service if it is killed to reclaim resources.
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // Return null because this is a pure started service. A hybrid service would return a binder that would
            return null;
        }


        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            // We need to shut things down.
            Log.Info(TAG, "OnDestroy: The started service is shutting down.");

            // Stop the handler.
            handler.RemoveCallbacks(runnable);

            //timestamper = null;
            isStarted = false;
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

create this class in native android

```
 namespace MAMN.Droid.Native
{
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = 
Int32.MaxValue)]


public class MessageBoard : BroadcastReceiver
{
    SmsMessage[] messages;
    public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (intent.Action != INTENT_ACTION) return;
            messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);          
            ManageSMS();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }


    public void ManageSMS()
    {
        var dd = messages[0].DisplayMessageBody.ToString();

       string msg = new String(dd.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());

        //this is the message center i have subscribe to get the message text in my pc
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "OTP", msg);
    }


   }
 }
```

then in main activity

```
       MessageBoard SMSReceiver = new MessageBoard();


        var smsFilter = new
        IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")
        {
            Priority =
        (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority
        };
        RegisterReceiver(SMSReceiver, smsFilter);
```

also give the permission in manifest 
hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for your response. It’s useful. Furthermore I’m looking for an example, how I can run this in background when the app is closed (service)

Comment: You need to put down some code which u have tried, read the stackoverflow guidelines to write the proper question

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I added it.

Comment: Dude this is a copy paste code from a reference, paste the code which u tried to achieve your requirement, read the guidelines

Comment: Like I wrote; I changed the code (of someone else) to solve my program (I added two lines to test if it works > it’s not working > I asked this question)